# SQL - Left Join return latest record

Tags: sql, date, left-join, teradata, record

My current code is:

```
SELECT
T1.SC,
T2.ACC,
T3.C_IDENT,
T4.TITLE,
T4.MID,
T4.SUR
FROM D_REG.AR_JOINT T1

LEFT JOIN E_BASE.ACC_TRANS T2
ON T1.SC = T2.SC
AND T1.ACC = T2.ACC
AND T2.IDENTIFEIR_END_DATE ='3000-12-31'

LEFT JOIN E_BASE.B_HOLDING T3
ON T2.M_IDENT = T3.C_IDENT
AND T3.EFF_END_DATE ='3000-12-31'
AND T3.P_HOLDING_END+DATE ='3000-12-31'

LEFT JOIN E_BASE.PNAM T4
ON T3.C_IDENT = T4.C_IDR
AND T4.EFF_END_DATE ='3000-12-31'
```

At the moment the code states to bring back a result if the End Dates = ‘3000-12-31’.
However, if any amendments are made to any of the columns within the table it will create a duplicate row for that record. The original will have an end date of the date the amendment was made while the new record will have an end date of ‘3000-12-31’.

My code will then only bring back active records. If the record is no longer active it will have an end date such as ‘2018-10-15’ and so returns ? ? ? ? values from T4.

How can I amend the code to bring back the record that has the latest end date instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Teradata, you can use [Qualify](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/huc7AEHyHSROUkrYABqNIg/GfvNZ6JRZUcXx0Ai971e5w) to constrain on ODAP functions, `ROW_NUMBER()` in this case..  Can't fully answer your question without knowing more about your data.  But basically, add to your query

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <YOUR KEY COLUMN(S) ORDER BY  T4.EFF_END_DT DESC) = 1
```

That will give you the most recent row (based on your column eff_end_dt) for each "key".

Comment: Thanks for the response- I tried this previous but ordering by a different end date, however, it only brings back 2187 results from the 3887 accounts I am looking for a result from...

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch the outer join. If not all rows in your driver table have corresponding rows in the table you're getting the effective date from, you may need to use coalesce with the date - something like `order by coalesce(t4.eff_end_dt,'9999-12-31') DESC`. Not sure if I'm picking the right table for the effective date either.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! My stupid mistake...I hadn’t removed the end date = from the original code. Removed that and run again with your original suggestion and it worked a charm 